# Get Image Results from API using PHP

Tags: php, html, json

I'm using the following api - https://habboapi.net/docs/badges/request (PHP Version) to pull Images from a Website.

It works https://beta.habbox.co/#content/habbo/badges and I have it displaying 540 "badges".

I'd like to add a search feature so you can search using the URL Parameters within the API

e.g. https://api.habboapi.net/badges?per_page=540&description=childline pulls all badges with any mention of the Word "Childline" within the description, or image name.

That way, when a user searches for keywords or descriptions, they get an output from the API.

Here is my current code:

```
            <div class="box">     
            <form action="" method="post" id="10">
<div align="center">
                <input style="width: 930px; height: 25px; padding: 5px; font-size: 16px; background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #EEEEEE , #fff); border: 1px solid #dddddd; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;" type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search Badges...">
</div>





<input style="display: none;" class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">


            </form>


</div> <br>

        <div class="box" align="center">


 <?php
// Fetch API Url
$api_url = 'https://api.habboapi.net/badges?per_page=540';
// Look for Badges
$badges = json_decode(file_get_contents($api_url), true); 
foreach($badges['data'] as $badge){
    // Echo out badges
    echo '<div id="rounded" style="width:44px; height: 44px;"><img src="' . $badge['image'] . '" /></div>'; 
}


?>


            </div>
```

I'm just in the early stages of learning PHP and really have no idea where to go, but I'm willing to learn and would appreciate the help on this!

Answer (score -1):

To check if the user has performed a search, you can check if the search input form was posted:

```
$search = isset($_POST['search']) ? $_POST['search'] : '';
```

Then, you can just append the value to the URL:

```
$api_url = 'https://api.habboapi.net/badges?per_page=540&description=' . $search;
```